# Check if INSERT mode is ON when typing in an input

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events

I'm trying to calculate the value of an input field on various events regardless of the event caught.

I'm taking into account the events `keypress keyup keydown cut paste` events (Do I forget anything?).

I'm trying to determine if the text-input `INSERT` mode is on (default - on), or off. I cannot determine the mode by capturing a key event of that key, though I don't know what was the initial state.

Does anyone know a way? Preferably - a cross browser solution that includes IE8+, Chrome and Firefox.

Any solution, or in the words of Barney Stinson, "scam, con, hustle, hoodwink, gambit, flim flam, stratagem, and bamboozle" that could help me would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just read the entire value each time?

Comment: With all those events, except for `keyup`, the input's value does not refresh until **after** the event is handled.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yea, I'm pretty sure the DOM doesn't expose *insert mode* state anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference, and that's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: Are you using a particular browser or does the solution have to be cross-browser?

Comment: It should be, but do you have any insight on one, at least?

Comment: @EXSlaver Sorry not yet no - saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561110/javascript-to-make-input-field-in-edit-modeinsert-mode#2561160), which only works in IE but it's for setting insert mode - haven't found an equivalent for checking the current state.

Comment: Yes, saw that as well..

Comment: Dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137172/determine-the-overtype-mode-using-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For IE only:

```
document.queryCommandValue("OverWrite");
```

As far as I know, Firefox and Chrome don't have *overwrite mode*. The insert key doesn't work in those browsers, and they are always in *insert mode*.

Moreover, Mac keyboard doesn't have a *insert* key from the beginning. So Safari also is always in *insert mode*.

Comment: That's a complete answer to my question.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct - unfortunately Chrome on Windows still has an overwrite mode in contenteditable elements. In form elements (input, textarea) there is no overwrite mode.  Tested on Windows 7 with Crome 41. https://jsfiddle.net/sw077y41/

Comment: For IE11, document.queryCommandValue("OverWrite"); is always giving me false

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't think you can directly access the state of the user's `Insert` status, you *can* figure out how long the strings are when the user is editing the field.

Consider this, tied with a simple `<input id="input" />`:

```
var i = document.getElementById('input');

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

    if(null !== c.match(/\w/)) {
        l = i.value.length;
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

    if(null !== c.match(/\w/)) {
        if(l === i.value.length) {
            console.log("Keyboard insert might be off - length hasn't changed");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is a rudimentary check to try and isolate *only* letters and numbers (with the `match` against the `keyCode` (borrowed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery)), as you don't want to perform the check against a shift key being pressed, for instance.

**Basic POC here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xp3Jh/**

I'm certain there are more in-depth checks you can do, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: That is not what I was looking for, though I try to get the value on any event of my choice, but this is a good detailed answer nonetheless. This code will not work on long key presses, but the point is clear.